# How to convert list of map to array of hash

Tags: java, arrays, json, list

I am using Java for my application. Here is the my input data.

```
  [{
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "one",
        "lastname": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstname": "two",
        "lastname": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstname": "three",
        "lastname": "3"
    }
  ]
```

I want to convert the above input to like below output. How can I achieve the below output in an efficient manner?

```
{
    ["id", "firstname", "lastname"], [1, "one", "1"], [2, "two", "2"], [3, "three", "3"]
}
```

**Update:**

I have tried the below. But it resulted as below

Expected:

```
result => {[lastname, id, firstname]=[[1, 1, one], [2, 2, two], [3, 3, three]]}
```

Actual:

result => {[lastname, id, firstname], [1, 1, one], [2, 2, two], [3, 3, three]}

**Code:**

```
 Map<String, Object> one = Map.of("id", 1, "firstname", "one", "lastname", "1");
        Map<String, Object> two = Map.of("id", 2, "firstname", "two", "lastname", "2");
        Map<String, Object> three = Map.of("id", 3, "firstname", "three", "lastname", "3");

        ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(one);
        list.add(two);
        list.add(three);

        MultiValueMap<Object, Object> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        Set<String> strings = list.get(0).keySet();

        ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map<String,Object> map: list) {
            objects.add(map.values());
        }

        result.put(strings, objects);
```

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Another thing that would be nice to clarify is why you want to do that? It sounds like a case of the XY problem.
Also what is your input guarantee? Do all maps have the same keys?

Comment: Can you share what was your approach to the problem ?

Comment: Are the keys presented in the same order?  And why you need to convert structured objects (which could be easily mapped to a POJO) to arrays of raw objects?

Comment: Yeah. Keys are in same order. It can be nested map.

Comment: @Touniouk I have update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input JSON may be read into a list of maps `data` sharing the same key sets and this list is to be converted into a list of object arrays, with the first element of this list being the keys of a map.

So, at first the array of field names should be created, converted to `Stream`, and then merged with `Stream<Object[]>` retrieved from the values of each map in `data` list:

```java
// using Jackson JSON to read the input
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String input = "[{\"id\":1, \"firstname\":\"First\", \"lastname\": \"Last\"}]";
List<Map<String, Object>> data = mapper.readValue(input, new TypeReference<>() {});

List<Object[]> output = Stream.concat(
        Stream.<Object[]>of(data.get(0).keySet().toArray()),
        data.stream().map(m -> m.values().toArray())
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.printf("Result: {%n\t%s%n}%n", 
        output.stream().map(Arrays::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(output));
```

Output:

```
Result: {
    [id, firstname, lastname], [1, First, Last]
}
[ [ "id", "firstname", "lastname" ], [ 1, "First", "Last" ] ]
```

---

Or similarly the result could be a list of raw collections based on maps' `keySet()` and `values`, which could be created like this:

```java
List<Collection> result = Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(data.get(0).keySet()),
        data.stream().map(Map::values)
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```